# Is there a way in hunchentoot to get the part of the url before the path

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

If a client makes a request for `proto://hostname:port/path` I would like to get `proto://hostname:port`.

I could have missed something but right now the only way I can think of is to use something along the lines of

```
(format nil "~A://~A" (stringify-downcase-scan (server-protocol*)) (host))
```

Is there any function/method specific for that or a simpler way?

The main reason is that `server-protocol` returns a keyword symbol (e.g `:http/1.1`) which I have to parse. Of course I can do it, but it is something that might already be there and I might have missed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [PURI](http://www.cliki.net/puri) or [QURI](https://github.com/fukamachi/quri) to parse URIs:

```
CL-USER> (describe (quri:uri "proto://hostname:1000/path"))
#<QURI.URI:URI proto://hostname:1000/path>
Type: QURI.URI:URI
Class: #<STRUCTURE-CLASS QURI.URI:URI>
SCHEME: "proto"
USERINFO: NIL
HOST: "hostname"
PORT: 1000
PATH: "/path"
QUERY: NIL
FRAGMENT: NIL
```

Then, you can do this:

```
(quri:render-uri 
 (quri:merge-uris (quri:uri "/")
                  (quri:uri "proto://hostname:1000/path")))

=> "proto://hostname:1000/"
```

In your case, you might want to access the URI with `(request-uri*)`.

Comment: Thanks but I want the reverse: to get the url string before the path, not to parse it. In the context of a hunchentoot request i implicitly have the parts: I have host:port from (host) method, and protocol from (server-protocol) method. I just have to parse/filter the response of the latter since it returns a keyword that contains the version number also

Comment: @Paralife Sorry, I am not sure to understand what you want. I tried to edit the answer to provide more details, but if this is not enough, could you add an example that shows how your handler is implemented? Thanks

Comment: (request-uri*) does not return the full url. It returns the part after host:port. To illustrate my problem better: Can you give me an example handler that  just outputs what the client has in the address bar? (up to the first hash of course)

Comment: @Paralife Ok, I understand now. It doesn't seem easy to get the whole path from a request, maybe there can be a way to define methods around some low-level Hunchentoot generic function like handle-incoming-connection, but I didn't try.